# Setting up MAAS on 14.04LTS Region + Cluster on same server DHCP not working

Tags: maas

First time trying out MAAS (want Openstack dev/test under cloud setup using MAAS). I want lab net <-> (eth0) MAAS Region & Cluster server  (eth1) [DHCP/DNS] <-> isolated net.  I installed via 14.04 LTS installer selected MAAS and after a couple hiccups I believe I have things mostly working (UI available) but I can't get DHCP on the isolated network.  One thing that troubles me is that I cannot ping the eth1 address of the cluster server.  I would appreciate troubleshooting tips for maas in general, things to look for in logs etc.  From the Cluster system I can ping it's own eth1 address but am getting Destination Host Unreachable for others on the (eth1) 192.0.2.0 network.

```
#cat /etc/network/interfaces
...
# The primary network interface
# This is an autoconfigured IPv6 interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
#iface eth0 inet6 auto
address 10.80.xxx.50
netmask 255.255.254.0
network 10.80.xxx.0
broadcast 10.80.xxx.255
gateway 10.80.xxx.1
# dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
dns-nameservers xxx.xxx.xx.132 xxx.xx.xxx.52 xxx.xx.xxx.41
dns-search xxx.com

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.0.2.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
up ip route add 192.0.2.0/24 via 192.0.2.1 || true   

# ip addr
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:1e:68:9b:2f:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.0.2.10/24 brd 192.0.2.255 scope global eth1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::21e:68ff:fe9b:2f6c/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

#ip route
default via 10.80.208.1 dev eth0
10.80.208.0/23 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.80.208.50
192.0.2.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.0.2.10
```

Answer (score 1):

This stumped me for a bit since it sure looked like eth1 wasn't connected into the right network but I saw all the cables connected.  The answer is that I actually hadn't screwed up my network/route setup but that I didn't realize that the udev rules for NIC mapping was different from what I had assumed it actually was.  My server's NetMgmt port is actually shares a physical connector between Service Processor and Server.  I've recalled and am reinstalling MAAS and things are going much better.